# Google sheets function IF, AND conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, worksheet-function, google-sheets-arrayformula

**EDIT 2: link to test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IWQWDK9piw_xFVm_48XZ8YAS_LQqXi6sd2GITLIfoAQ/edit#gid=903221057**

**EDIT 1: added a column, so now J=K, K=L, L=M  | updated formulas to reflect the column changes**

I'm trying to do conditional formatting (highlight cell) in column M (M:M) when **cells in columns K and L are not blank and the corresponding cell in column M is blank**. Basically, when the following criteria are met:

- K:K>0 (if cell has a number, don't count NAs)

and

- L:L has a date (so don't count blanks and NAs)

and

- **M:M is blank**

---

The formulas I found were:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND(isnotblank({
```

But I couldn't set it up right... not sure exactly how this gets set up.

---

```
=and(K:K>0, L:L>0, M:M="")
```

L:L>0 captures NA (seems to capture all values). How do I get it to capture only dates (not date range). I was told to use "if_date()" but this also doesn't work

---

```
=countifs(K:K,">0",L:L,">01/01/1998",M:M,"")
```

Highlights the ENTIRE column M, instead of relevant cells. When I pasted the function into a cell (instead of the conditional formatting box), it correctly counts 1 cell. However, I want conditional formatting to highlight the cell itself. The highlight range is set to M:M. Why isn't this working?

---

```
=countifs(K:K, ">0", L:L, "if_date()", M:M, "")
```

Tried this formula and nothing highlighted

---

```
=IF( AND(ISNUMBER(K1:K), ISBLANK(M1:M)), COUNTIFS(K1:K, ">0", L1:L, ">"&DATE(0,1,1)))
```

**This does highlight empty cells in M when criteria are met, but also highlights the empty cells in M when criteria in L are not met (when a cell in L is blank). My criterion for L: must contain a date**

---

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- in this conditional-formatting-scenario is **`=ArrayFormula()`** kind of not necessary.
- to hide **#N/A** you can use **`=IFERROR()`**
- to avoid **#N/A** you can use **`=ISNUMBER`** **`=ISDATE`** **`=ISBLANK`** **`=ISTEXT`** etc.
- and this custom formula is what you seek:

```
=IF( AND(ISNUMBER(J1:J);
         NOT(ISBLANK(L1:L))); COUNTIFS(J1:J; ">0"; 
                                       K1:K; ">"&DATE(0;1;1)))
```


it checks if **J** has number 
and **L** is not blank 
and then it checks if **J>0** 
and **K** **>1st january of year 0**.

be sure you have right formatting otherwise it wont work:

[image]

## update 1:

- **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ktS4GJA79t8FYYnYknlhDr07I2AB0LNy58AFknFc-tY/edit#gid=1931505287)**

## update 2:

- **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IWQWDK9piw_xFVm_48XZ8YAS_LQqXi6sd2GITLIfoAQ/edit#gid=903221057)** where custom formula is:

```
=IF( AND(ISNUMBER(K2), 
         ISBLANK(M2), 
         ISDATE(L2)), COUNTIFS(K2, ">0", 
                               L2, ">"&DATE(0,1,1)))
```

Comment: thanks for this! i added a column so J=K, K=L, L=M and removed the "NOT" from "NOT(ISBLANK(" since i actually want it to highlight the blank cells. this is what i used: =IF( AND(ISNUMBER(K1:K), ISBLANK(M1:M)), COUNTIFS(K1:K, ">0", L1:L, ">"&DATE(0,1,1))) but it seems to disregard the condition for L (has a date). it highlights the empty column M cells when L is blank and when L has a date. how can i make sure it only captures the cells that have a date in column L?

Comment: i also tried this formula, but nothing highlighted: =countifs(K:K, "isnumber", L:L, ">"&DATE(1990,1,1), M:M, "")

Comment: i tried adding ISDATE(L1:L) but nothing highlights. =IF( AND(ISNUMBER(K1:K), ISDATE(L1:L), ISBLANK(M1:M)), COUNTIFS(K1:K, ">0", L1:L, ">"&DATE(0;1;1))).

Comment: i removed the countifs part, figuring that the first part of your formula covered my criteria, but nothing highlighted. the formula: =IF( AND(ISNUMBER(K1:K), ISDATE(L1:L), ISBLANK(M1:M)))

Comment: @quesyrahsarah looks like you have wrong formatting... K column needs to be formatted as a number, not text. see: https://i.imgur.com/SOEsphk.png?1

Comment: should i format column K as number>plain text or number>number? tried both and the formula is still coloring blanks in col. M when L has a date AND when L is blank (which is not what I want). when i also format col. L (date) as a number, nothing is colored in col M. basically, the formula is completely disregarding col L. it will highlight blank cells in M when a cell in K has a number. but it's supposed to work only if col L has a date as well. this is the formula i'm using, courtesy of you ;)    =IF( AND(ISNUMBER(K1:K), ISBLANK(M1:M)), COUNTIFS(K1:K, ">0", L1:L, ">"&DATE(0,1,1)))

Comment: @quesyrahsarah would be so much easier if you would share a copy of your sheet... see this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ktS4GJA79t8FYYnYknlhDr07I2AB0LNy58AFknFc-tY/edit#gid=0

Comment: thanks so much for this. unfortunately, your test sheet doesn't highlight the right cells. 3 cells that matched the criteria didnt highlight (i left comments).  i created a test sheet. i want blank M cells to be highlighted if K has a number and L has a date. If K doesnt have a number and/or L doesnt have a date, then M shouldnt highlight, even when blank. sheet1 is the test sheet. sheet2 shows which cells should be highlighted when the conditional formatting works https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IWQWDK9piw_xFVm_48XZ8YAS_LQqXi6sd2GITLIfoAQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: @quesyrahsarah now we are getting somewhere finally :) check out 2nd update in my answer. the missing part was `ISDATE()`

Comment: thank you thank you!! it almost worked. we are so close! not sure why on my actual sheet (not test sheet) it still highlights M cells when L is blank. i've formatted column K as number>number, column L as date, and column M as number>number. i think it might be due to the range you entered. how did you decide this? I entered M:M which gsheets turns into M1:M1034. Is there a way to make sure it applies to all cells in column M and is dynamic (when i add a row it includes it in the conditional formatting)?

Comment: @quesyrahsarah just select M2 > right-click it > go to Conditional formatting > set range M2:M and use last formula from my answer as it is  (**update 2**)

Comment: YOU ARE AN ANGEL! thank you very much for being so patient and helping me. sorry, i forgot to tell you i added headers. your new formula works perfectly `=IF( AND(ISNUMBER(K6), 
         ISBLANK(M6), 
         ISDATE(L6)), COUNTIFS(K6, ">0", 
                               L6, ">"&DATE(0,1,1)))`

Answer (score 0):

Must of the conditional rules applied to a column should be written by using the reference of the topmost cell, in other words,

instead of

```
J:J
```

use

```
J1
```

By the other side, to test if a cell has a

- number use ISNUMBER
- date use ISDATE
- cell is not blank use ISBLANK inside NOT

Comment: thanks, @ruben! sheets automatically converts J:J into J1:J1033 after i save the formula so there's no need to use J1

Comment: @quesyrahsarah Are you saying that using J:J the conditional formatting works?

Comment: no the conditional formatting doesn't work. i was just clarifying that J1:J didn't need to be specified since gsheets automatically corrects my J:J into J1:J1033. i create a test sheet. i want blank M cells to highlight if K has a number AND L has a date. if K doesnt have a number and/or L doesnt have a date, then M cells shouldnt be highlighted even if they're blank https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IWQWDK9piw_xFVm_48XZ8YAS_LQqXi6sd2GITLIfoAQ/edit?usp=sharing